# How I can store 3 element from one array at the one cell in another array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have this array that is contain 12 number 
P =  [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ]
I want to put each 3 elements from this array at one cell at 2d matrix in matlab to make 2x2 matrix with each cell have one point with this formula (x,y,z) but I have problem in this line ( I think the concept is wrong!)

```
x(i,j)= cpoints(counter) cpoints(counter+1) cpoints(counter+2);
```

Complete Code:

```
p = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
nr = 2;
nc  =2;
counter = 0;
for i=0:(nr-1)
   for j=0:(nc-1)
      x(i,j)= p(counter) p(counter+1) p(counter+2);
      counter = counter +3;
   end
end
```

I want the result like this [ (1,2,3) (4,5,6); (7,8,9) (10,11,12) ]

Comment: Several comments: (1) arrays/matrices in Matlab can only hold primitive types (eg. default is a double) (2) a "cell array" in Matlab can hold an arbitrary data type in each cell (eg. another matrix) (3) the first element in an array in Matlab has an index of 1, not 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily avoid loops thanks to the `reshape()` function, which (as its name suggests) reshapes an array. In your case you can do:

`p=reshape(p,3,[])';`

in order to get

```
p =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

The reshape function takes as first input the array you want to reshape (`p`) as the following arguments are the dimensions. However, `reshape()` works filling the reshaped array by columns whereas in your case you want it filled by rows. So at first we reshape the array with 3 rows (second argument) and let Matlab evaluate the number of columns accordingly (third, empty, argument). Later on we transpose (`'`) the result in order to get the final matrix.

However, if for any reasons you have to use loops, a simple solution can be:

```
nc=3;                   % set the number of columns as 3
nr=numel(p)/nc;         % evaluate the number of rows
k=1;                    % this index will scan vector p
for i=1:nr              % in Matlab indices start at 1, not 0
   for j=1:nc
        x(i,j)=p(k);    % fill element (i,j) with the k-th element from p
        k=k+1;          % keep scanning p
   end
end
```

A final note: in Matlab you cannot store 3 elements inside a single matrix element. Although you can fill an entire row as I did above and then in order to get the triplet (x,y,z) you can read the entire row. To read an entire row from matrix `X` you can use the syntax `X(i,:)` where `i` is the row index: this command will return a vector, that is the matrix row.
If you want a vector inside a single element you must use cell arrays and not regular matrices.

Comment: if I used reshape can I plot each row as one point on axes (x,y,z) in this case?

Comment: @SamahAhmed You know that all the x-coordinates are on the 1st column, all the y-coordinates are on the 2nd column and all the z-coordinates are on the third column. You can read an entire column by using the command `X(:,i)` where `i` is the column index (*i=1,2,3* in your case). So you basically plot the first column vs the second column vs the third column

Comment: Thank you for your great answer